# SQLite select that ignores a dot in the middle of a number

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible to build a select query that the input is 5102 and in locates the value 5.102 in a sqlite database?

```
|Value1 | value2 | value3 | Text |
--------------------------------
|5.102  | 6.102  | 7.102 | Text1 |
|5.103  | 6.103  | 7.103 | Text2 |
|51.02  | 61.02  | 71.02 | Text3 |
```

User search for 5102
returns

```
5.102 Text1
51.02 Text3
```

Comment: you mean add a dot after first digit ?

Comment: No the user inputs 5102 and the data selected in the table is 5.102

Comment: You user inputs 5102 and db have 5.102,51.02, 510.2, 4.111 but sql query give only 5.102,51.02, 510.2 in reponse. Is this you want?

Comment: @Arfan Mirza Yes, That's it

Comment: Post your table structure... And few sample values also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your problem well, one solution could be to preselect the values with a replace statement, and then perform a query on that table.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select *, replace(value1, '.', '') as changed_value1 from your_table
) AS P 
WHERE P.changed_value1 = '5102'
```

`P` is a table with all your initial values, plus `changed_value1`, which is a `value1` without dots.

When you perform a replace on a field, sqlite coerces it automatically to string even though the value represents an int, and therefore the quotes in the number.

Answer (score 0):

|Value1 | value2 | value3 | Text | DecimalPlaceHolderPosition

1. |5102 | 6.102 | 7.102 | Text1 | 1
2. |5103 | 6.103 | 7.103 | Text2| 1
3. |5102 | 61.02 | 71.02 | Text3| 2

Now in application use combination of Value1 & DecimalPlaceHolderPosition to represent as decimal number. By this your app will be save from sql complex processing, like convert to string and remove dot or use regex operation etc.

Now you need on simple search query

"select * from tbl where Value1=5102 group by Value1"

Arfan Mirza